# Does Snap work with templates

Tags: snap.svg

index.html file as below: This HTML is compiled with Handlebars

```
<div id="svg"></div>
```

index.js file as below:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);
```

When i executed my code. It is showing me following error:

```
TypeError: s.circle is not a function
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to attach Snap to a div element, instead of an SVG element.

Try changing

```
<div id="svg"></div>
```

to

```
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

You can always put the svg inside a div.